# How to use cURL to consume an Apache CXF Web Service that take bytes as parameter?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, curl, cxf

This is my Web Service

```
//the Web Service
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
 public Response upload(byte[] input) {
     // store input somewhere
     System.out.println("Done");
     return Response.ok().build();     
 }
```

How can I test it with cURL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the binary is in a file, for example an image or something, you can try like this:

```
$ curl -X POST -d @image1.png  -H content-type:application/octet-stream http://yourserver/path
```

Comment: @qannoufoualid appreciate if you can accept & upvote the answer